# Bivariate isotonic regression on unbalanced grid

Tags: r, isotonic

I would like to do classic isotonic regression on bivariate data (that is to say, x with two columns). The function biviso of package Iso is very fast but requires a balanced grid. I would like to do isotonic regression on unbalanced grid. For example:

```
x1 <- runif(100)
x2 <- runif(100)
y <- x1*x2 + rnorm(100)
```

Is there an R package or custom R code that can do this? By "classic" isotonic regression, I attempt to make reference to the following definition, which is in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotonic_regression):

$$
{\displaystyle \min \sum _{i=1}^{n}w_{i}(x_{i}-a_{i})^{2}}
$$

$$
{{\text{subject to }}x_{i}\leq x_{j}{\text{ for all }}(i,j).}
$$

The weights $w_i$ are not important for my usage so we can define $w_i=1$.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I think of is using monotonic splines through [`scam`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scam/index.html). That way we will constraint the fit of each term to be a monotonic function giving us a monotonic response. I prefer it to other functions that solve the constrained optimisation problems directly because it gives us access to (most of) the diagnostic goodies we get from `mgcv::gam`.

```
set.seed(5)
x1 <- runif(100)
x2 <- runif(100)
y <- x1*x2 + rnorm(100)
my_data = data.frame(x1=x1, x2=x2, y=y)
library(scam) 
my_model_sc <- scam(y ~ s(x1, bs="mpi")+ s(x2, bs="mpi"), data=my_data)
```

A quick visual inspection confirm that our fit is monotonic along `x1` and `x2` too.

```
library(pdp)
pd <- partial(my_model_sc, pred.var = c("x1", "x2"), smooth = FALSE,
              grid.resolution = 100, progress = "text" )
plotPartial(pd)
```

[image]

If we are looking to replicate something closer to the step changes seen in QP solutions, we can look into [`cgam`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cgam/index.html).

```
library(cgam) 
my_model_cg <- cgam(y ~ incr(x1)+ incr(x2), data=my_data)
```

Here we can specify an increasing but smoothed fit through `incr` (they are other options to have smooth convex or concave fits, etc).

I append a bit of code below  showing how both functions allow us to have a monotonic fit across values of `x2` for a fixed `x1`.

```
my_data_2=my_data[order(my_data$x2),]
my_data_2$x1=0.5;

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(x=my_data_2$x2, y = predict(my_model_cg, newData = my_data_2)$fit, lwd=2,
     t='l', xlab="x2", ylab="f(x1=0.5, x2)", ylim=c(-0.4,0.5), main="CGAM fit")
grid()
plot(x=my_data_2$x2, y = predict(my_model_sc,newdata =my_data_2), lwd=2,  
     t='l', xlab="x2", ylab="f(x1=0.5, x2)", ylim=c(-0.4,0.5), main="SCAM fit")
grid()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your kind time! I am hoping to use classical isotonic regression as defined on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotonic_regression). I should have added link as reference. I apologize for my carelessness. Thank you for this new technique. I also am interested in studying it one day.

Comment: Nothing to apologize for. That said, this is: "*fitting a free-form line to a sequence of observations such that the fitted line is non-decreasing (or non-increasing) everywhere, and lies as close to the observations as possible.*" (as Wikipedia defines it) We use monotonic regression like Dette et al. (2006) in [`monreg`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/monreg/index.html) were we circumvent the quadratic programming formulation. Just instead of smoothing via Nadaraya-Watson (as in that paper) we smooth with splines.

Comment: If it is the smoothness constraint that breaks the deal, I will write something with [`cgam`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cgam/index.html).

Comment: You are right. I did not know "isotonic regression" was not well-defined (?). I have updated the question to refer to "classic" isotonic regression and given definition. I would be interested in how you remove smoothness constraint with cgam. It would be interesting to compare performance with the classical isotonic regression. However, I am still interested in classical isotonic regression. If there is an answer that allows classical isotonic regression I will choose it. Thank you for your time and flexibility. +1.

Comment: Cool, I am glad I could help. I added a relevant example. Please note that both examples provided, do minimise exactly what is described in the Wikipedia page subject to smoothness constraints (in the case of `scam`) on the isotonic estimator.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that only smoothness constraint is the difference. Interesting indeed. One more question: is it true that the model assumes additivity or am I misreading the code? I know GAM in general assumes additivity, but mgcv package has nice ways to handle bivariate smooth as well so I'm not sure if that is allowed in scam.

Comment: Yes, it the isotonic estimator assumes additivity (like most linear models, nothing special there). `scam` does not allow for bivariates smooths when I checked it.

Comment: I see. I was not aware of this implicit assumption (although from the code it is indeed obvious). I do not think the generally defined isotonic regression (i.e., the quadratic program without smoothness constraints) requires additivity.

Comment: Additivity concerns the estimator. QP concerns the optimisation technique. The QP will aim to fit step-functions in the end of the day; PAVA (pool-adjacent-violator algorithm) tries to solve this in a more efficient way but they are other ways too. You might want to check Tibshirani et al. (2011) [Nearly-Isotonic Regression](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/papers/neariso.pdf) for a cool re-formulation of PAVA.